# Nexus One can boot only with USB fastboot

Tags: fastboot

After making some changes to my Nexus One, I can't boot it normally, but I can boot it with USB fastboot, like this:

```
$ cd 1.0-GRI40-nexusone-superboot
$ ./fastboot-linux boot boot.superboot.img
```

How do I make it work so that it can boot up by default, without an USB cable connected and the fastboot command issued on my PC?

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked:

```
$ cd 1.0-GRI40-nexusone-superboot
$ ./fastboot-linux flash:raw boot boot.superboot.img
```

I've found the necessary info on http://www.gotontheinter.net/content/fastboot-cheat-sheet